# Finding all the multiples of 3 and 5 in the range of 100 using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multiple-select

I'm an absolute beginner to programming and I've been doing simple tasks like this one.
And I dont really see how I'm getting 2 different results in these codes below.

```
total1 = 0
for element in range(1, 100):
    if element % 3 == 0:
        total1 = total1 + element
print(total1)
#1683

total2 = 0
for element in range(1, 100):
    if element % 5 == 0:
        total2 = total2 + element
print(total2)
#950

print(total1 + total2)
#2633
```

And then a different way of computing the multiples giving me a different result.

```
total = 0
for element in range(100):
    if element % 3 == 0 or element % 5 == 0:
        total += element
print(total)
#2318
```

Mathematically if I'm not wrong the sum of the multiples of number 3 and 5 in the range of 100 is 2633 but I cannot figure out why the other solution gives me 2318.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Because you are counting e.g. 15 twice, which is incorrect.

Comment: Please edit your post and put codes in code area.

Comment: Note that your first code could be faster and more concise: `total1 = sum(range(0, 100, 3)` and same for `total2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is when element is a number that is both divisible by 3 and 5. In your first method, that number will be added to the total twice, whereas in the second it will only be added once.

You can check it by looking at what happens in each case when `element = 15` for example. In your first code, both `total1` and `total2` will add 15, making the sum of `total1 + total2 = 30`.  Whereas in the second method, you only add 15 to the total once, making the overall total just 15.

You need to work out which method you want to happen when a number is divided by both, should it be added twice? or just once?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
Honestly this was my first tought and I've checked it and still got a wrong answer and now that you have said this I've checked it again and the answer was good!
I've missed checking one multiple at my first try... :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: @Sw4y glad to have helped. If this answered your question, it would be good if you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left :)